# Adding legend to plot in ImageJ

Tags: java, imagej

I'm a bit stuck in a small problem with [ImageJ plots](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/gui/Plot.html).
I need to add a simple legend. I have two lines (one is red and the other one is blue) and I want to add a sidenote that explains that line red is function "a" and line blue is function "b", but i can't understand how to use addLegend method in Plot class. Can you help me? An example would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get it.

```
    plot.addLegend("A\nB");
```